# Format date in Windows 7 batch job

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd, format

I'm trying to use the current date in a Windows 7 batch job.  The batch job opens multiple files which have today's date appended to them. 
Example:

```
start \\\Directory_Name\Rpts\20130801\0000A060_FileName_20130801.pdf

start \\\Directory_Name\Rpts\20130801\0000P083_FileName_20130801.pdf

start \\\Directory_Name\Rpts\20130801\00007P12_FileName_20130801.pdf
```

If I run echo `%date%` I get:
"Thu 08/01/2013"

I know I can run `echo %date:/=%` and get:
"Thu 08012013*"

But I want to remove the "Thu" (today's day) and format the date to "20130801" (yyyymmdd) instead of mmddyyyy.

So eventually the open file command would look like the following with the correct `%date%` command inserted:  `start \\\Directory_Name\Rpts\%date%\00007P12_FileName_%date%.pdf`

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit simpler of a way of doing it with substrings:

```
set buildDate=%DATE:~4,10%
set dateStr=%buildDate:~6,4%%buildDate:~3,2%%buildDate:~0,2%
```

Comment: This is working, almost.  The date is showing up as 20130108 and I need it to be 20130801.  Sorry, I tried to play around with your code, but I couldn't comprehend what is doing what.

Comment: Here's the skinny: %buildDate:~6,4% will start at the 6th position in the buildDate string and copy 4 characters, so it will copy the "2013" of "08/01/2013". So all you have to do to change it to yyyymmdd is switch the ~3,2 and the ~0,2 parts from above around to form: set dateStr=%buildDate:~6,4%%buildDate:~0,2%%buildDate:~3,2%

Answer (score 13):

A robust, region insensitive method:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
set timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%
set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution, that is independent of local time format:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
```

and then `%datetime:~0,8%` will give you your `YYYYMMDD`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It uses a for-loop to process the dates content:

```
for /f "delims=/ tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%date%") do (
rem Lets name our new variable "rdate" for reverse date
set rdate=%%c%%b%%a
)
```

That should work fine. Just call it as %rdate%.

Hope this helped, Mona

Comment: Note this will only work in a batch file, to use it in cmd then replace `%%` with `%`.

Comment: Note: this will only work, if you add a double quote after `%date%`.

Answer (score 0):

I use it to change the date temporarily.

```
set buildDate=%DATE:~4,10%
set dateStr=%buildDate:~0,2%-%buildDate:~3,2%-%buildDate:~6,4%
net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
        goto check_Permissions
    )
    echo Permissions Administartor!!!
    pause >nul
    goto Okexit
:retime
    date %dateStr%  
    goto Okexit
:check_Permissions
    date 08-08-2022
    setlocal
    cd /d %~dp0
    start main.exe 1 0 kRzTzfbOG8Gd9AozkZxCM5W8RgOTnEoDmJRKJ5i0WiWApEojgD4Pq8GMCu/nr2OL4w/rgfe0J4eTPmMD
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 >nul
    goto retime
:Okexit
```

Comment: The `%date%` variable is not locale independent as the format will depend on the region of the system. I would recommend using the methodology found [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-stampme.html).